# Getting Plugins to work with Eclipse Helios 3.6

Tags: plugins, eclipse-3.6

I have been searching for a new IDE for a while. I finally decided to try Eclipse, although I am a little discontent with the memory usage, and I really like a lot of aspects about it. There are, as with learning any new IDE, some things that I haven't been able to figure out yet. One of the biggest ones is that it seems like no matter what plugin in I install it doesn't work, or doesn't appear to.

I downloaded Eclipse Galileo just to make sure that I could get plugins working there, since I know Helios is pretty new, and plugins worked in Galileo as expected. Is there something different that you have to do in Helios that I haven't discovered yet or am I missing something?

I have tried installing RSE, Subclipse, and Drupal for Eclipse (I am a Drupal developer). None of these work in Helios, but all work in Galileo.

Any help from Eclipse users would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you finally made eclipse work??

Answer (score 0):

There's the new marketplace, so rather than using

Help -> Install New Software,

check out

Help -> Eclipse Marketplace.

I've had a similar issue with the m2eclipse plugin, but found installing it through the marketplace worked fine!

Comment: I tried installing Subversive using Help -> Eclipse Marketplace like you suggested and I still do not see any SVN functionality options. My Helios Build ID is: 20100617-1415 in case that matters at all.

Comment: Hmm, sorry to hear that.

The only other thing I can think of then (which I also had issues with) is :

I'm a Linux (Arch to be exact) user and had installed Eclipse through the package manager. This install seemed screwed up, so I installed the standalone version from the Eclipse website and this seemed much better quality.

Otherwise I'm not sure sorry